# Where does the Drupal 8 page serving mechanism go after index.php?

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-8

Drupal 8 seems to serve the pages from the cache whenever available. I have a page which embeds a couple of views with past events and present events corresponding to the current date. The page is being cached by Drupal cache and the events are not moving from the upcoming section into the past section. The page works fine when the caches are disabled.
Where can I override the cache and set a variable so that caches are flushed every 12 hours?

I've tried many hooks like the preprocess in a custom module already. But the parameter values I fetch in these modules are also getting cached by Drupal